# Tomcat 6: How does Http11NioProtocol work without servlet 3.0?

Tags: tomcat

I need to decouple request handling threads from background processing threads. Is this possible with Tomcat6? It offers the Http11NioProtocol connector, but to my understanding, Servlet 3.0, which is necessary for asynch processing, is introduced in Tomcat7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Tomcat you can create an [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) to do your background processing. Or you could even spawn your own threads - or go for a more comprehensive solution of using JMS, using e.g. ActiveMQ to do async processing - either in the same JVM or on a different JVM.

Some care must be taken, as if you reload your webapp, all threads you explicitly create, or implicitly by using an ExecutorService must be stopped - so you need to establish a [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) that shuts down these when the context is destroyed.